Using MultiThreading to Call and API. How to get kill slow processes?
I need  to kill tasks that are running long.
I have a bunch of api calls that I need to make. I'm currenting using ThreadPoolExecutor to have 12 workers to run in parallel. Each worker will call the api and return a result that I then join back together.
The problem is that the api that I'm calling takes around 20 seconds if it works and around 500 seconds if it's going to fail.
The problem is as far as I can tell, ThreadPoolExecutor has a timeout, but can't kill executing workers. It'll just tell you that a task took longer than you asked it to take. Requests.get also has a timeout, but this timeout isn't for the duration of the request, it's for when the server has not issued a response for timeout seconds.
Is there anything else that I can do to cancel the long running tasks that I know will fail?
Code has been simplified to:
def process():
    response = get(url, stream=True, verify=self.cert, params=params, timeout=timeout)
    return response

Simple ThreadPool
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_threads) as executor:
            output = list(
                executor.map(self.process, df.to_dict(orient="records"))
            )

More complicated ThreadPool
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.num_threads) as executor:
            futures = {executor.submit(process, record) for record in df.to_dict(orient="records")}
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                start_time = time()
                try:
                    process_data_output = future.result(timeout)
                except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
                    logger.warning("Failure: Timeout Error. Timeout: %s seconds.", timeout)
                    future.cancel()  # Attempt to cancel the task
                duration = time() - start_time
                logger.info("Success: Timeout not met. Process took %s seconds", duration)


Thoughts?
I've tried changing looking into both timeout options, but neither one seems to be able to cancel the job if it takes a long time.

There is no built-in mechanism to kill a thread in Python, and even less if they're in the midst of a blocking call such as a synchronous HTTP request.

If you're on a Unix-type platform you can do some trickery with SIGALRM. Also, returning a streaming response from the thread is not a great idea especially as you're (effectively) handling the streams from each API call synchronously

Research more and ask a specific question with a [mre]. If you are using stream=True, you must implement a loop to iterate the response body. Why not exit the loop when a timeout occurs?
